# How to use wavelet decomposition for feature extraction (for fMRI images)?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, signal-processing, feature-extraction, wavelet-transform

I have a dataset consisting of fMRI images (from mice) which are divided into 4 groups (different drug dose levels applied). Each fMRI image is 4D, that means each voxel is a time series. For each fMRI image I want to extract one feature vector.

Now I want to use wavelet decomposition for feature extraction. In Matlab there exist no 4D wavelet decomposition, so I turn the 4D images into 3D by taking the average of the time series. Then I could apply 3D wavelet decomposition and taking the LL component as features, that means doing something like that:

```
WT = wavedec3(fMRI, 4, 'db4');
LL = WT.dec(1);
temp = cell2mat(LL);
feature_vector = temp(:);
```

Of course afterwards feature selection algorithms (like recursive feature elimination) could be applied to reduce dimensionality.

What do you think of this approach? Are there better approaches?

Comment: Are your images aligned ? 
I would guess the difference of intensity between the drug doses images is something you want to capture.

Comment: Yes, the images are aligned.